# Profile default identicon color is suddenly different

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

For the past five years, 10 months my default Stack Exchange profile "identicon" has been an orange color. However, suddenly within the past few days it turned green.

[image]

**Current Color:**

[image]

Why did it suddenly turn green, and how do I get the original one back?

Comment: @AdamLear: Thank you — I appreciate the information.

Comment: *If* you still want the old one back, you can take a screenshot of it and upload it as your profile picture.